# How to fix "Cancel & Voice button on left" in RTL Search Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, right-to-left, searchbar, android-search

I developed an **RTL** android app. I implemented an *Actionbar* that contains a *Search bar*. but the `Cancel` and `Voice` button are on the **right** of the text.

As you know, the cancel and voice button must be on the **left** of the text in RTL.

[image: RTL Search Bar]
[image: RTL Search Bar]

**Notice:**

- I've added the `layoutDirection` & `textDirection` for all of
  *AppBarLayout*, *Toolbar* & *SearchView*.
- I've added the `android:supportsRtl="true"` at *Manifest* too.
- I've set `Gravity` to `End`.

**Layouts:**

`app_bar_home.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    tools:context=".home.Home">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:textDirection="rtl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:textDirection="rtl"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_home" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

`menu_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:title="@string/search_hint"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```

`searchable.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"/>
```

`Manifest`:

```
<activity
    android:name=".home.Home"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
</activity>
```

So, How can I change the position of SearchBar Buttons to the left?

Comment: lets see your layout

Comment: I add the layouts and styles in the description now. @Ogbe

Answer (score 0):

you can set `rtl` diration just for toolbar .

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
```

and customize your toolbar .

Comment: I mentioned that I it that, for both `Toolbar` and `AppBarLayout`. but still, the buttons are on the right.